# Where and how to store data locally using $.post

Tags: javascript

I am using this code to edit data on table ,this is allowing me to edit data ,but I am not able to find that where and how should I store data locally on that form itself ,if i don't want to store it in database, I want to know what this `"/somewhere"` should be(url or some file or what).

```
<table id="mylist_remark"><tr>
    <td class="editable" contenteditable="true">Something</td>
</tr></table>


$("#mylist_remark .editable").bind("blur", function(e) { 
  console.log($(e.target).text());
  $.post("/somewhere", {remark: $(e.target).text(), candidate_id: $(e.target).nearest("tr").attr("id")}, function() { console.log("success"); });
   });
```

Comment: You're not *supposed* to write data on the client!

Answer (score 0):

> ... how should I store data locally on that form itself ,if i don't want to store it in database...

One solution would be to use `localStorage` to save the form elements locally.

If you felt like using jQuery, you could make the problem simple:

```
$("input").change(function(){
    var input = $(this).val();
    localStorage.setItem("input",input);
}
```

Then when the page loads, you set the `val` to the `localStorage` item:

```
var input = localStorage.getItem("input");
$("input").val(input)
```

[More on localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage), and even [more on localStorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp).

Comment: And also [`IndexedDB`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB). [Each of them has its own advantage.](http://csimms.botonomy.com/2011/05/html5-storage-wars-localstorage-vs-indexeddb-vs-web-sql.html)

Comment: but it do not support Internet Explorer 7 and earlier versions,i need it to work in them also